# How to find Oracle APEX WORKSPACE NAME and USERNAME?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Hello everyone I have VMware which I used to practice `Oracle` `APEX 5.0` , currently I'm not able to login to `Oracle APEX` because I don't know my `worksapce name` and the `username` to login to apex, I still have access to Oracle database through the `system` user , I just need a `query` that allow me to retrieve the Oracle APEX username and the workspace name ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of workspaces: when you query list of users:

```
SQL> select * From all_users;

USERNAME                          USER_ID CREATED
------------------------------ ---------- ----------
XS$NULL                        2147483638 29.05.2014
MIKE                                   71 30.03.2018
SCOTT                                  66 03.03.2018
APEX_040000                            47 29.05.2014   --> this
APEX_PUBLIC_USER                       45 29.05.2014
```

you'll see the APEX user; on my XE database, it is Apex 4.0 that installs by default.

Once you find the APEX_ username, find all workspaces as

```
SQL> select workspace from apex_040000.apex_workspaces;

WORKSPACE
---------------------------------------------------------

HR
INTERNAL

SQL>
```

As of usernames, try with

```
SQL> select user_name from apex_040000.wwv_flow_fnd_user;

USER_NAME
---------------------------------------------------------
ADMIN
HR

SQL>
```

Comment: not all the queries work for me but I edit some of them and work ...thanks I managed to find the username ...but I still can't find the workspace name

Comment: When connected as a privileged user, try this: `select * From dba_objects where owner = 'APEX_040000';` (of course, use your own APEX_... user) - it'll return all objects owned by that user. Include a WHERE clause which might look like `where object_name like '%WORKSPACE%'`, maybe you'll find something useful.